# Django: Is it necessary to call select_for_update for recently created object in atomic transaction?

Tags: django, transactions, atomic, django-orm

I have a view with atomic transaction, where one object is created then updated:

```
def buy(request):

    with transaction.atomic():

        # get request.user for update
        user = User.objects.select_for_update().get(id=request.user.id)

        user.order_count += 1

        # get other stuff for update
        items = Item.objects.select_for_update().filter(sold=False)

        items.update(user=user)

        # DO I NEED select_for_update SOMEWHERE HERE FOR NEXT UPDATE?
        new_sell = Sell.objects.create(user=user)

        # some_operations()

        new_sell.some_field = something
        new_sell.save()

        HttpResponse('Done')
```

Is it safe to update newly created objects without select_for_update() in atomic transactions?

Or how do normal people implement select_for_update in such cases?

I guess, this will be 100% safe, but does not look like a good plan:

```
new_sell = Sell.objects.create(user=user)
sell = Sell.objects.select_for_update().get(id=new_sell.id)
# Now we can do everything with sell object
```